# How to include WooCommerce selected product variation details in a custom message

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I added a button "Order on WhatsApp" in WooCommerce product page, and when clicked it redirects to WhatsApp with prefilled message like "I want to buy: product name and product URL".

Here is my code :

```
function ecommercehints_content_after_add_to_cart_form() {
    // Get the ID of the current product
    $product_id = get_the_ID();

    // Get the product's title
    $product_title = get_the_title($product_id);

    // Get the product's URL
    $product_url = get_permalink($product_id);
    ?>
    <style>
    .order_on_whatsapp {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #131313;
        padding: 10px;
        vtext-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 700;
        border: 2px solid #5e51b6;
        font-size: 115%;
    }
    .order_on_whatsapp:hover{
        background-color: #6051BA;
        color: #fff;  
    }
    .order_on_whatsapp img {
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 14px;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    // Output the WhatsApp button with the product's title and URL in the pre-filled message
    echo '<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+918488806776&text=Hello,%20I%20want%20to%20buy:%20' . 
    $product_title . ' (' . $product_url . ')" class="order_on_whatsapp">
    <img src="https://woo.cdesksolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/whatsapp.webp" width="14px">
         Enquire on Whatsapp
    </a>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'ecommercehints_content_after_add_to_cart_form', 30);
```

Is it possible to show the selected variant and its price in the message?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Sorry, you are right. Actually I added the code but I was showing some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variable products, you need something different using JavaScript, that will allow to set the product name, the product price and the product URL data in your WhatsApp Custom Button link data.

Here is the complete code for simple and variable products:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'ecommercehints_content_after_add_to_cart_form', 30);
function ecommercehints_content_after_add_to_cart_form() {
    global $product;

    if( ! is_a('WC_Product', $product) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }
    // Not for variable products
    if( ! $product || 'variable' === $product->get_type() ) return;

    // Get the product name
    $product_title = $product->get_name();

    // Get the product URL
    $product_url = $product->get_permalink();

    // Get the product price
    $product_price = strip_tags( wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) ) ) );
    
    // Button CSS
    ?>
    <style>
    .order_on_whatsapp {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #131313;
        padding: 10px;
        vtext-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 700;
        border: 2px solid #5e51b6;
        font-size: 115%;
    }
    .order_on_whatsapp:hover{
        background-color: #6051BA;
        color: #fff;  
    }
    .order_on_whatsapp img {
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 14px;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    // Output the WhatsApp button with the product's title and URL in the pre-filled message
    echo '<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+918488806776&text=Hello,%20I%20want%20to%20buy:%20' . 
    $product_title . '%20-%20' . 
    $product_price . '%20(' . $product_url . ')" class="order_on_whatsapp">
    <img src="https://woo.cdesksolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/whatsapp.webp" width="14px">
         Enquire on Whatsapp
    </a>';
}

// Add variation custom field data to single variable product form
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'add_variation_custom_field_to_variable_form', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_custom_field_to_variable_form( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_data['name']  = $variation->get_name(); // Product Variation name
    $variation_data['url']   = $variation->get_permalink(); // Product Variation URL
    $variation_data['main_url'] = $product->get_permalink(); // Parent Variable Product URL

    return $variation_data;
}

// For variable products
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'display_selected_variation_custom_field_js' );
function display_selected_variation_custom_field_js(){
    // Button CSS
    ?>
    <style>
    .order_on_whatsapp {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #131313;
        padding: 10px;
        vtext-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 700;
        border: 2px solid #5e51b6;
        font-size: 115%;
    }
    .order_on_whatsapp:hover{
        background-color: #6051BA;
        color: #fff;  
    }
    .order_on_whatsapp img {
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 14px;
    }
    .order_on_whatsapp.disabled {
        opacity: .5 !important;
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }
    .order_on_whatsapp.disabled:hover {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #131313;  
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    
    // Javascript
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        var href = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+918488806776&text=Hello,%20I%20want%20to%20buy:%20';
        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
            $('.order_on_whatsapp').removeClass('disabled').attr( 'href', href + data.name + '%20-%20₹' + data.display_price + '%20(' +  data.url + ')' );
        }).on('hide_variation', function(event) {
            $('.order_on_whatsapp').removeAttr('href').addClass('disabled');
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
    // Display button
    echo '<a class="order_on_whatsapp">
    <img src="https://woo.cdesksolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/whatsapp.webp" width="14px">
         Enquire on Whatsapp
    </a>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you very much @LoicTheAztec. It is working. 
There are some issues, if you can help me please.
1. It doesn't show product title for variable products(Hello, I want to buy: - $948 (https://woo.cdesksolutions.com/product/anti-burst-gym-ball-w-pump-75-cm/?attribute_size=45 cm))
2. It changes the url of the product, can we keep the url as it is and add the Variant in the next line like this : Variant : Size =45 cm
3. The Price currency is different then the store currency, can we fix that?
I know I am asking much, but I am new to these things. Please help.

Comment: I have updated the code, to show the missing product title et the correct shop currency. For the Product variation URL, it is generated by WooCommerce. Now you may try to replace in `get_selected_variation_data_js()` function code, the Product variation URL `data.url` by the parent Variable product URL`data.main_url`.

Comment: It is working. Thank you. Sorry, but Still having some issues. 
1. The styling of the button is different for simple and variable products.
2. For Simple products prices looks like this(shows sale, regular and discount as well) :(Hello, I want to buy: Camera Lens Shaped Coffee Mug Flask With Lid - ₹201.00 ₹120.00₹81.00 off (https://woo.cdesksolutions.com/product/camera-lens-shaped-coffee-mug-flask-with-lid/))

I really appreciate your help and support. Thank you.

Comment: It is working as excpected. Thank you very much

Comment: will the same method work in shopify, I know shopify has different language but still any hope?

Comment: @chirag I really don't know anything regarding Shopify code, sorry.